# Вывод группами в django

Tags: шаблоны, django

Необходимо вывести нечто вроде этого:

```
<div class="scrollable"><div class="items">
    <div><img src="1" alt=""/><img src="2" alt=""/><img src="3" alt=""/></div>
    <div><img src="4" alt=""/><img src="5" alt=""/><img src="6" alt=""/></div>
    <div><img src="7" alt=""/><img src="8" alt=""/><img src="9" alt=""/></div>
</div></div>
```

Из массива вида ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']. Как это лучше всего сделать, учитывая то, что количество элементов в массиве может быть любым (от 1 до бесконечности).

Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Помогло

```
<div>
{% for item in items %}
<img src="{{item}}" />
{% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:"3" %}
    </div> <div>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: Хорошее решение, возьму на заметку, что этот фильтр в таком случае можно применить.